# inverse of integral transform

Tags: integration, integral-transforms

given a general integral transform

$$ g(x)= \int_{0}^{\infty}dyf(y)K(xy) $$

for a general formula of the kernel $ K(xy) $ is there an inverse of the Integral transform to obtain $ f(x) $ from above

lets say that there will always be a function $ B$ so

$$ f(y)= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{C} dsB(ys)g(s) $$

as in the case of the inverse Laplace transform

Comment: The inverse Laplace transform is not an integral over a closed contour, but is an integral over a line in the complex plane perpendicular to the real axis.  We close the loop so we may use Cauchy's theorem to evaluate the integral.